# Arabic text not shown after pdf is genereated using itextsharp

Tags: .net, pdf, itext

```
                        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (var reader = new PdfReader(investorapplicationpdf))
                        {
                            using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, memoryStream))
                            {
                                AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
                                string email = dr["Email"].ToString();
                                form.SetField("Nationality", fullname);
                                stamper.Close();
                            }
                        }
                        modifiedPdfBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    }
```

I am using this code to open a PDF then apply data coming from DB and setting them in the field , but there is one major issue that all the english character are shown perfectly but the Arabic character are not shown initially but when I click on the field it shows the character but when I click on other field its same as empty for the Arabic field.

I am sharing the Screen shot of the PDF

[Before Clicking on the Textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8FFc.png)

[After Clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM8ax.png)

please go through the image and tell me where the problem is actually
I am working in itextsharp 5.5.13 in .net 4.8.1 so give suggestion accordinly

Comment: can you also share the code on how you sent the fonts for the document/fields? can you share the PDF file?

Comment: unfortunately cause of some reason i cannot share the whole share pdf , and data is coming directly from the DB in Datatable